# Parsing XML files, Android NDK, SDL2

Tags: android, c++, xml, android-ndk

Ay up.

I'm currently in the process of making a game - it's a C++/SDL2/OpenGL combo which on PC works reasonably well. The long-term goal is to make this portable, though given that I lack most of the equipment to shove it onto every platform under the sun, the first "port", as it were, is likely to be for Android-powered phones and tablets.

SDL2 has an official (or "officially endorsed") port to Android, and after many weeks of haggling with Java and Eclipse and a mostly broken OpenGL ES 2.0 renderer, I've got stuff running on my lovely Nexus 7 tablet. It's not fast or pretty, but it's something to build on.

However, my game, as I would imagine many games like it, relies heavily on reading (and writing) data to and from XML files, be it saves, options, levels, you name it. But the Android NDK compresses all but a few file formats upon compilation - SDL2 has functionality to claw out images and audio from the Android-created /assets/ folder (where all my stuff is stored), but I use [TinyXML2](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2/) for my XML handling, which can't cope.

There seems to be a small handful of possible solutions (it's a problem that turns up quite a bit - I'm well aware the "Similar Questions" box on my right is filled with similar woes as I type this), but each one seems to have either pretty big caveats or make pretty big assumptions about how the code is written. End results often being pointers to wacky variable types that won't fit neatly into tinyxml2, or I get stuck half way through because it turns out a piece of the puzzle isn't there. It's super frustrating.

Method a) seems to involve decompressing the apk at runtime and accessing the assets by brute force. It sounds like a really bad way of doing things and in some cases seems to assume the apk is placed in a specific location. Sounds pretty terrible to me, and complicated to achieve?

Method b) has the Java side effectively pass a pointer to the Android asset manager to the C++ side. This seems better, but examples I've seen of Java-to-C++ Android communication seem geared around very small "Hello World"-style projects where you're just passing across a string or a number. I also read this involved compiling Java headers and doing something novel with that- a process that would then fail because the Android asset manager isn't a standard data type or whatever.

c) SDL_RWops is meant to be geared up for Android and may be a preferable way of reading data from files. But it doesn't solve the subsequent brick walls as I try to convert this stuff into something tinyxml2 will understand.

Method d) seems to suggest you can get away with changing the extension of assets to that they're not compressed. So all my XML files become unofficial PNGs or whatever. That sounds terrible too, not least because I have 40+ XML files that would need to be managed. Supposedly there's a way to adjust what files are or aren't compressed, but some seem to think it's all or nothing, and I'm not sure how it's done regardless.

Understand that when you've been at at this for hours it's easy to let yourself be mislead. While I acknowledge the merit of figuring this stuff out for yourself, clues online are often incomplete, out of date, or are flat-out wrong.

So yes, a simple guide would be lovely. I've wasted many days exploring options and I'm sure it would be beneficial to the world to have a definitive answer.

As said, this works fine through the Windows PC build - reading and writing isn't a problem so I know it's not something stupid like dodgy files. For the Android port I'm using Eclipse and as said, the tablet I'm testing on is a Nexus 7. I have working knowledge of C++ and Java, but these fiddly bits drive me round the bend.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well okay, I've taken a bit of a break and returned to this puzzle, and given that the situation hasn't really changed in terms of online tutorials or documentation or whatever, I've gone for the stupid option (option d) - I wrote a batch file to convert my XML files into JPEGs en masse, and now the program looks for JPEGs to read from and write to. How terrible.

On the plus side, tinyxml2 appears to be loading these fake JPEGs, but things crash as soon as it's given the command to look inside for specific elements, leading me to think it's probably not loading things properly (but at least it's no longer crashing on file load).

Debugging is painful and this whole strategy feels dirty and wrong. And there's nothing more disheartening than struggling with a question that presumably almost every Android game developer working in C++ has already answered in some form. Reading and writing files - why is this a challenge?